# Multiple IP assigned on a single interface, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, proxy, ip, squid

I have a range of public, I need to assign them all on a single physical Interface using Alias, but Iafter I added them it seems there is a problem when I restart the interface. here is the configuration

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 51.x.x.x
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        network 51.x.x.x
        broadcast 51.x.x.x
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        post-up route add 46.x.x.x dev eth0
        post-up route add default gw 46.x.x.x
        post-down route del 46.105.116.254 dev eth0
        post-down route del default gw 46.x.x.x


auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 51.x.x.x
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        network 51.x.x.x
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        post-up route add 46.x.x.x dev eth0:1
        post-up route add default gw 46.x.x.x
        post-down route del 46.105.116.254 dev eth0:1
        post-down route del default gw 46.x.x.x
```

Comment: What is the problem? Add more information about the problem you see.

Comment: Actually it works fine later, I realised it was the problem of cloud and MAC that has been assigned into the physical interface. so yeah now every thing works well. thank you.